# Rearranging the formula in order to get the value of alpha

Tags: trigonometry

Hello I have a very simple question yet, I cannot solve it. This is the formula

$μH = \frac {\sin (\alpha)} {\cos(\alpha)}$

$\sin$ divided by $\cos$ is $\tan$ so I did that

$ μH = \tan(\alpha) $

Now I have the value of $μH = 0,7$ but I need to be able to calculate alpha. I've tried putting the value of $0,7$ and getting the tan value of that but that just doesn't make sense. Any advice on how to solve this

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. You should choose your tags carefully. What has this to do with `linear-algebra`?

Comment: Sorry that was a mistake, to be fair I'm not certain what part of math this is.

Comment: By $\mu H=0,7$ do you mean it is $0.7$? [i.e. using comma for decimal point] If so $\alpha=\arctan(0,7)$ or that plus a multiple of $\pi$.

Comment: @codeisfun It's about `trigonometry`.

Comment: Yes I was using a comma for decimal point, but I am not sure what you are saying with plus a multiple of pi?

Comment: Oh arctan, didnt see that there, thank you for your help!